# Difference between Configurable vs Grouped Product?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, products, grouped-products

What is the difference between configurable and grouped product, it has similar functionality have child and associated products, but i want to know the core difference.

Answer (score 2):

**Configurable Product:**

1.It is like a ‘’simple product’’ with its multiple attributes.

2.You cannot add multiple associated products of configurable product to cart

3.With Magento 2 configurable product, you have to do the math to get the price. The price of the children product will be equaled the price of the configurable product plus the price of the chosen attributes.

4.When using the configurable product in Magento 2, customers only add each child product to cart.

5.This type of Magento product is still suitable for selling clothes with different size and color, which will have an appropriate performance for customers experience.

**Grouped Product:**

1.The grouped product like its name, it looks like you are selling a group of products.
2.You cannot add multiple associated products of configurable product to cart.

3.Customers can conveniently add these group of products or multiple associated products to cart at once.

4.You can use the grouped product to sell multiple simple items as groups or sets such as a set of clothes, set of furniture, and so on or you can sell clothes, furniture individually if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Configurable and Grouped Products both are completely different.

**Configurable Products:**

A configurable product looks like a single product with drop-down lists of options for each variation. Each option is actually a separate simple product with a unique SKU, which makes it possible to track inventory for each product variation.

For example, dress with different colors and sizes available.

In Cart Parent (configurable) Product will be added with selected child product options. Also order item table 2 records will create one for parent product and another for simple product.

You could achieve a similar effect by using a simple product with custom options, but without the ability to track inventory for each variation.

**Grouped Products**

A grouped product consists of simple standalone products that are presented as a group. A grouped product provides an easy way to offer variations of a product, and list them all on the same page. Presenting a grouped product can create an incentive for customers to purchase additional items.

For example, you might sell open stock flatware, and list every type of utensil that is used in a formal place setting. Some might order multiple salad forks, fish forks, dinner forks, dinner knives, fish knives, butter knives, soup spoons, and dessert spoons.  Customers can order as many of each item as they want.

Although they are presented as a group, each product in the group is purchased as a separate item. In the shopping cart, each item and the quantity purchased appears a separate line item.

Hope this help !!

Answer (score 0):

- `Configurable product` is a number of different but related items 
  in which the user selects one of them by choosing an options. 
  For example, Shirt could have many different sizes like , Small, Medium, Large. 
  Every size is a different physical qty but the customer just goes to the shirt page and then selects a size.
- `Group Product` is like a cover that holds the real products. 
  So the products which constitute Group Product are the real existing products. 
  Group Product is just a platform where we can see a couple of related products together.
  Like, Computer(Group Product) : Monitor, CPU, Mouse, Keyboard (many products)

Answer (score 0):

**Grouped Product:**

The grouped product represents a **selection of products consolidated on one product page**. There is a quantity box for each item, so if your customer wants 2 or 3 pieces of a specific item, he/she can indicate quantity in the corresponding box. Shoppers, who visit your store can either buy the whole set, means an entire grouped product or choose, for example, one product from the group. They are not obliged to purchase all the components if they do not need them.

**Configurable Product:**

Magento configurable products can be defined as **single items that comprise selectable variations**. This product type allows shoppers to customize their purchase, choosing the necessary option from the list of offered product variants. Configurable help you create the main product with certain characteristics that are customizable. Respectively, clients can adjust the purchase and choose from the drop-down the option that suits the best.

Each product variant is a separate product with distinct SKU and inventory level that makes it possible to control variation stock. Associated products can be sold either as part of the configurable product or as separate products.